# Show that if A is self-adjoint and $A^{2}x=0$, show that $Ax=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I feel like i'm overcomplicating this a bit.

Let $X$ be a finite-dimensional inner product space and $A$ be a linear transformation from $X$ to $X$. If A is self-adjoint and if $A^{2}x=0$, show that $Ax=0$.

Here's my thought:

$0=\left<A^{2}x,y\right>=\left<A(A^{*}x),y\right>=\left<A^{*}x,A^{*}y\right>=\left<Ax,A^{*}y\right>$

The first equality just came from the fact that $A^{2}x=0$. So the last equality has to be zero as well. I just don't know how to show that $Ax$ specifically must be zero, because as its written, I think $A^{*}y$ could also be zero while $Ax$ is non-zero. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if $y=x$? When is a norm zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the following:
$$A^2 x=A(Ax)=0$$
This means $Ax$ is in the null space of $A$. $Ax$ is also in the range of $A=A^*$. However, [according to Proposition 0.4 on this document](http://math.mit.edu/~trasched/18.700.f10/lect17-article.pdf), the range of $A^*$ and the null space of $A$ are orthogonal complements, so there's no way $Ax$ can be in both of them unless $Ax=0$.

Answer (score 4):

$0=\langle A^2x,x\rangle=\langle A(x),A^*(x)\rangle=\langle A(x),A(x)\rangle=\|A(x)\|^2=0$. Since the norm of $A(x)$ is zero, $A(x)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

It's useful to know that if $X$ and $Y$ are finite dimensional inner product spaces over $F$ (where $F$ is $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$) and $A:X \to Y$ is a linear transformation, then $A$ and $A^* A$ have the same null space.  Here's a proof: Clearly $Ax = 0 \implies A^* Ax = 0$.  Conversely,
\begin{align*}
& A^* A x = 0 \\
\implies & \langle x, A^* A x \rangle = 0 \\
\implies & \langle Ax, Ax \rangle = 0 \\
\implies & \|Ax \|^2 = 0 \\
\implies & Ax = 0.
\end{align*}